# Google Drive opens in VS Code

Tags: unity, visual-studio-code, online-accounts

I added my Google account in the Online services in Ubuntu Unity 22.10.
My Google drive showed up in the launcher, and was working fine until I installed VS Code. Now, clicking on the Google drive folder is opening VS Code (which is failing to show my files in Google drive).

How to fix this? I want to open my Google Drive with my file manager (nemo).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to set the preferred file manager to open directories. E.g., for Nemo,

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```